# NodeJs and NowJs on EC2 lose connection

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, nowjs-sockets

I have deployed NodeJS and NowJS to be a messaging server on EC2, when I logged on to EC2 and start with command "node server.js" it works fine. but if I start in the background and loggout out from EC2 with command "node server.js & > node.out"

Sometime Jetty (Webserver) can't connect o NowJs. I'm not sure why that happened, Am I missing something?

This is my code.

```
var http = require('http');
var httpServer = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
});

httpServer.listen(3000);

var nowjs = require("now");
var everyone = nowjs.initialize(httpServer);
everyone.now.distributeMessage = function(ids, message){
    everyone.now.receiveMessage(ids, message);
};
```

BTW I can still see http://localhost:3000/nowjs/now.js in firebug on EC2, but when I call everyone.now.distributeMessage. I got error saying that It's undefined. But when I logged on to EC2 and start the server again, it works fine.

Comment: Run "node server.js" and leave your window open for a while. A long while, run your servers as usual. That way, when node.js crashes, you'll be able to see the error and backtrace.

Comment: I don't see any error from the stacktrace. But still my webserver throws error that everyone.now.distributeMessage is undefined for sometime. :(

Comment: This post helps me http://blog.nodejitsu.com/keep-a-nodejs-server-up-with-forever

Comment: What version of NowJS are you running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with the command you provided your process is running in your user's ssh session. when you logout the session goes away. it could be as simple as using **nohup**.

try this:

```
nohup node server.js & > node.out
```